# Html.dropdownlist set unchangeable option

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my ASP.NET view, how do I use the dropdownlist helper to set an option in a select and make it unchangeable? It has to be a select element for various reasons, or else this would have been an easy problem. I have this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("transactionTypeID", Model.TransactionTypeIDList, "")
```

Assuming I already know what every option in TransactionTypeIDList is, how can I set the select element to this option and then set the select element to disabled?

Comment: you want to  make dropdown disable???

Comment: Yeah, how do I select an option in this dropdown and disable it before it gets sent to the client?

Comment: you want to set dropdown value from controller action or user will select value ???

Comment: Do you want to show the **value** that corresponds to this id, instead of the **ID** itself in the dropdown?

Comment: The select is filled with options like: <option value="1">foo</option>. How do I set the dropdownlist to the option with value 1 before sending it to the client? The select list should just show "foo".

Comment: @imdabestmanideedeet - Check my answer, You must be using a strongly typed view right? Just pass the value you want set in dropdown say `1` in a property and set that as the first param in `DropDownListFor`, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

To disable your dropdownlist, use something like:

```
@readonly="readonly"
```

will stop the user from being able to select the dropdown

So, add this after your `@class` or `@id` attributes

becoming:

```
@Html.DropDownList("transactionTypeID", Model.TransactionTypeIDList,
      new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly="readonly" } })
```

You can use this 'readonly', or even there's `@disabled` html attribute as well

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

If, say, you wanted to **populate** your dropdown with a value instead of the ID (which may be easier for client's understanding), I would recommend [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search) tutorial in which (about halfway down) shows you how to do this.

Comment: @chridam: are you sure about that? I've been using this in multiple mvc projects?

Answer (score 0):

For selecting the dropdown list and disabling the selected value you can use [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx) like this:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.YourProp, Model.TransactionTypeIDList, "Select", new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Here, `YourProp` will be the property present in your model, by which you want to show the dropdown as selected.